# Is it possible to have an invisible desktop

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, wmctrl, gtk-2

Note, I've rephrased my question below in *edit 2*.

I really like Ubuntu 20.04s desktop system, I am however looking to make a small script to add some functionality to my system and was wondering it is would be possible to have an "invisible" Desktop. This would mean that it wouldn't normally be accessible unless I use a specific command (I've for now been using wmctrl to interact with my WM but I don't seem to be able to do this with wmctrl).

Another option would be to create and destroy a Desktop dynamically.

Edit: "Invisible" here is referring to it being invisible to the user with the standard GUI use cases (So I wouldn't want it showing up where all your "normal" desktops show up and it shouldn't be accessible with `ctrl+alt+arrow` either). This may just be completely impossible as well, I'm kinda trying to make an add-on to the GUI without actually changing the GUI...

Edit 2: It seemed that my question wasn't that well worded, so second try.
I want to have a place for a (python) script that I wrote to do things with (x)windows. I'd prefer it if this workspace wasn't visible to the user and if the only time that they interacted with this workspace would be when my script puts them there (aka makes the "secret" workspace the active one). Is there a way to do this with hidden workspaces? if not, would it be possible to simulate this by creating and destroying my "hidden workspace" dynamically when I need it, or would that just be to big a mess to attempt to do?

Comment: Re: "it wouldn't normally be accessible unless I use a specific command" ⇢ how would this be different from locking the screen, thus preventing other people from accessing anything? 

Comment: I wasn't refering to my screen. Ubuntu 20.04 has "virtual desktops" which you can switch between (I usually have 2-3 desktops open). I can see them and move through them with the GUI. With invisible I meant invisible for the GUI/key combos (ctrl alt up/down can move you between desktops for example)

Comment: I've seen nothing like this in the 15-odd years that I've used Ubuntu. Generally speaking, if the person in front of the keyboard is not supposed to see/have access to something, then they shouldn't be in front of the keyboard. This is what different user accounts and account switching is for 

Comment: Yeah, I think that I may just have to reserve Desktop 0 for this. tbh, I am kind of trying to make a GUI extention while working far away from the actual GUI xD

Comment: Please add any explanation to the question itself: use "edit". It is currently quite unclear what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: The term you are looking for is perhaps _workspace_, not desktop.

Comment: Are you looking for some sort of [tag:kiosk] mode?